# How to open a directory using c#

Tags: c#, directory

I am new in `C#`. I am searching a directory and opening that if it is available. I am using the following code:

```
if(Directory.Exist(pathOfDir))
{
    //open the directory for user
}
```

But I don't know **how to open the directory**, any `Directory.Open()` method could help me. Kindly tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Process.Start(pathOfDir);
```

It starts a process, you can also open webpages using this method.